# CSS drop-down menu disappear when trying to mouseover it

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, mouseover

I created a menu and a drop down sub menu. But when I try to mouseover the submenu, it disappears.

I tried some solutions recommended on the net, but couldn't correct it.
Can someone help to correct it?

Thanks

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Company Background</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Company Awards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services Program</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Yamaha</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Yamaha</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News and Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Branches</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
</ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS is as follows:

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 20px;  
    list-style:none;
    position:fixed;
    display:inline-table;   
}

nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    float:none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}

nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #757575; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/3hV27/

Comment: It works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/LLzcX/

Comment: Check link on http://jsfiddle.net/nkGmw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine here. What browser are you using?
[image]